# JCalendar customization

Tags: java, calendar, customization

I 'm trying to use [JCalendar](http://www.toedter.com/en/jcalendar/index.html) but i'm not sure it has all the abilities i need.

1.Is it possible to select multiple dates?
2.Is it possible to change the background color and how?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Selecting multiple dates: Out of the box, no, this isn't possible.
Changing background color: Out of the box, yes, but only insofar as you are changing from one prepackaged look-and-feel scheme to another.

This is an open-source project under a GNU Public License, though, so you could make the appropriate modifications yourself.

Answer (score 0):

And you can Simply Highlight Date and can do that stuff.

```
http://www.zfqjava.com/docs/componentpack/calendar.html
```

that will help.